# React Forms : How to make input data as list objects with same input name?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-final-form-arrays, react-forms

I'm Posting input data to API's where the API's structure as array list with n objects.

Problem: The problem I'm facing is while handling the change, i'm replacing the data instead of inserting as an another object.

My code as follows:

the objects in the list is dynamic not limited to two

in Constructor->

```
this.state={
formData: [
        {
          information: "",
          from: "",
          to: "",
        },
        {
          information: "",
          from: "",
          to: "",
        },
      ],
}
```

handling the Change as follow:

```
handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const { formData} = this.state;
    this.setState({
        formData: {
          ...formData,
          [name]: value,
        },
      });
```

Handle submit:

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.formData);
    }
```

Form fields as follows:

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
<div>
 <input  type="text"   name="information"   onChange={this.handleChange}   />
 <input  type="text"   name="from"          onChange={this.handleChange}   />
 <input  type="text"   name="to"            onChange={this.handleChange}   />
</div>
<div>
 <input  type="text"   name="information"   onChange={this.handleChange}   />
 <input  type="text"   name="from"          onChange={this.handleChange}   />
 <input  type="text"   name="to"            onChange={this.handleChange}   />
</div>
.
.
.
<button> + Add new Set (div) </button>
<button type="submit"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

I'm aware that mistake is handing logic but i tried lot to correct. Please help me out.

Edit: Expected output:

```
 [
        {                    
            "information": "info  1",
            "from": 1,
            "to": 50
        },
        {                    
            "information": "info  2",
            "from": 51,
            "to": 80
        },
        {
            "information": "info  3",
            "from": 81,
            "to": 100
        }
    ]
```

Comment: You are changing the formData from an array to an object in your handleChange function. Do you want to just append and object or replece something?

Comment: You need some kind of track to track from which input its change. As in your input name is not unique identifier

Comment: @Viktor I need to append new <div>'s which have input fields if user clicks on add button, these inputs should be {} in []

Comment: then you should do something like `this.setState([...formState, {}])`

Comment: @Viktor on submit, returing empty array

Answer (score 2):

If you want to insert a third object to formData you need to add curly brackets {} to frame `[name]:value` as an object. Also `formData` is an Array so it must be with square brackets not curly ones.

```
this.setState({
        formData: [
          ...formData,
          { [name]: value }
        ],
```

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to use `prevState` in `setState`.

```
this.setState(prevState => ({...prevState, [name]: value }))
```

This will guarantee that you always use the previous state. `setState` is an async function, if you use `formData` it will not guarantee that the changes that you already dispatch are in place to be used.

Answer (score 1):

```
state={
formData: [
        {
          information: "",
          from: "",
          to: "",
        },
        {
          information: "",
          from: "",
          to: "",
        },
      ],
information:"",
from:"",
to:""
}
 
...

 <input  type="text"   name="information"   onChange={(event)=>{this.setState({information:event.target.value})}   />
 <input  type="text"   name="from"          onChange={(event)=>{this.setState({from:event.target.value})}  />
 <input  type="text"   name="to"            onChange={(event)=>{this.setState({to:event.target.value})}   />

...

handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
const data={  information: this.state.information,
          from: this.state.form,
          to: this.state.to}

    this.setState({formData:[this.state.formData,data]})

    console.log(this.state.formData);
    }
```